# Generic function to find child elements without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a generic set of functions so that I can check if children of a particular element, with a particular feature exist. Unfortunately, for this task I don't have jQuery available to me.

A function call example:

```
has_child_with_id(element, 'obj123');
```

I'm trying to keep it compatible with the maximum number of browsers, and I'm aiming to have some explicitly named functions to find by name, id, class etc.

I'm still new to the javascript module pattern, but would something like this be appropriate?:

```
var myfunctions = (function() {
    var public_interface = {
        // NAMED FUNCTION
        has_child_with_id: function(el, n) {
            return public_interface.has_child_with_('Id', el, n);
        },
        // GENERIC FUNCTION
        has_child_with_: function(type, el, n) {
            // Option 1 (querySelectorAll)
            return typeof el['querySelectorAll'] === 'function' && el['querySelectorAll']('['+type+'="'+n+'"]').length > 0

            // Option 2 (get a bunch of elements, doesn't work on forms)
            || typeof el['getElementsBy'+type] === 'function' && el['getElementsBy'+type](n).length > 0

            // Option 3 (get a single element)
            || typeof el['getElementBy'+type] === 'function' && typeof el['getElementBy'+type](n) !== 'undefined'

            // Option 4 (Manually loop through elements)
            || (function(children, n) {
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
                    if (children[i].hasOwnProperty(type) && children[i][type] == n)
                        return true;
                }
                })(el.getElementsByTagName('*', n));
        }
    };

    return public_interface;
})();

alert(myfunctions.has_child_with_id(document, 'myid'));
```

Comment: Your query selector method should come after checking for IDs or class names, those functions are far more efficient than the way you're doing that query selector.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might consider to a) not put the generic function on the public interface or  b) not use that `public_interface` variable but simply access properties on `myfunctions`, but in general it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` actually fits the bill here nicely. It's IE8+ compatible (IE9 if you're using CSS3 selectors). Rather than searching the document, simply prefix with the element you want to search within.

Get the first element that matches a class, ID, or data attribute.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');
var firstMatch = elem.querySelector('.sample-class');
```

Get all elements that match a class, ID, or data attribute.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');
var allMatches = elem.querySelectorAll('.sample-class');
```

In this case, `firstMatch` and `allMatches` are the ones you're looking for.

You could also search by ID, data attribute, or another other valid CSS selector:

```
elem.querySelectorAll('[data-something]'); // Matches by data attribute
elem.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); // Returns all checkboxes
```

`querySelectorAll` will return an array of nodes that you can loop through.